# Listview with a List<object> and multiple properties as a datasource

Tags: c#, listview

Is it possible to bind a `List<object>` to a `ListView` and use more than one property as display members?

The object contains in total 3 properties:

```
String name;
String email;
Int cost;
```

Please refrain from using for/foreach/while loops as I'm looking for a solution that utilizes databinding.

Comment: You can make a custom datasource that has a `List<object>` internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a custom property with only getter and combine properties in the getter

Comment: This works only if you want to display all the values in a single column.

Answer (score 1):

use a [dataview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.dataview%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) ( with databinding if you are in WPF )

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WinForms, instead of using `ListView`, you can use an [`ObjectListView`](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html), which I find is an easier way to hold classes in that type of control without all the casting problems.

However, if you are using a `ListView` you will have to suck it up and add in each item individually.